# XMPP Sending Messages on Location Based Criteria

Tags: xmpp, postgis, publish-subscribe, ejabberd

I am writing a custom service using XMPP protocol, ejabberd server and PostGis spatial database. Also I am writing the clients to the service, so I have complete control.

User Alice comes online and need to publish information to certain user entities which are within proximity to her.
So user Alice login create pubsub node, I want the other proximity entities to be automatically subscribed to Alice's node.

When Alice comes online I need automatically to query postgis about entities within proximity and automatically subscribe them to Alice.

Which way would you recommend?

Thanks
Eylon

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing standard for doing exactly this, but XEP-0060 can be extended to accomplish this.

In a system I developed I made it possible to subscribe to a point+radius, within a node. This is accomplished via the [subscription options](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#subscriber-configure-subandconfig), such as:

```
<iq type='set'
    from='francisco@denmark.lit/barracks'
    to='pubsub.shakespeare.lit'
    id='sub1'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <subscribe node='princely_musings' jid='francisco@denmark.lit'/>
    <options>
      <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
        <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
          <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscribe_options</value>
        </field>
        <field var='location#latitude'><value>52.231</value></field>
        <field var='location#longitude'><value>-1.49</value></field>
        <field var='location#radius'><value>10</value></field>
      </x>
    </options>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

Then I customized the pubsub service to filter notifications according to the area in the subscription options. Things only really get complicated when items are moving location, and you need to emulate a retract when an item previously published to a client goes out of range of its subscription area.

Unfortunately I can't offer any code as it is not public (not my choice), though it's for Prosody anyhow, and it looks like you are looking for an ejabberd solution. The principle I describe above is working well for me though, so I suggest it as a template solution at least.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am a bit confused. The iq stanza you wrote is a request to join a node. In my case Alice would be the node creator and the subscribed entities will be the entities arround her. All this have to happen without end user intervention. So maybe you mean Alice's client will create a point+radius node and on the server side I will intercept the node creation and do automatic subscription of all nearby entities. This offcourse will involve doing the spatial database query inside my XMPP server.

Comment: Ah ok, your case is a little different to mine. It sounds like rather than items having location (as in my example) you need *nodes* to have locations. And for subscribers to have automatic subscriptions to nodes within a certain distance from their current point. Correct?

Comment: Multiple nodes is a little more difficult - you could automatically subscribe the user to new nodes, but the client won't actually know it has been subscribed. At that point you may as well just send it unsolicited notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ejabberd, but I would think a custom module that does the correlation between location tracking and subscription management would be the simplest.  This type of application specific behaviour is typically supported in most XMPP servers by usage of curomt plugins/modules.

Comment: In this case I will do the spatial database query within my XMPP server modue? @Robin